# Adding facebook profile picture to high scores table using PHP

Tags: php, database, facebook

I was able to make a small flash game after receiving a lot of help here at Stackoverflow, I was able to post the score variable to a php file and then to database , now I would like to make a small high score list and I know I would need to use the FB users and scores previously saved to the database’s table, my question is how could I add the profile picture thumbnail besides each user’s score ? Should I save another parameter to the database or should I use  the following  line when I print the databse info in the html file ?

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<USER_ID>/picture"/>
```

I’m really sorry if this is a silly  question, I’m really inexperienced with facebook stuff.  Thanks!

Comment: This is the best way to display profile photos.  You can even add parameters to it to get some other sizes - `https://graph.facebook.com/UID/picture?type=large`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed the best way to display profile photos of your users (or any users).  There is no need to store URL's or even download the images to your server. All you need is the users Facebook ID.

If the pictures are those of the users friends, the chances are that they already have those images cached in their browser so it's a good idea to take advantage of that.

You can also add some parameters to that call to get other sizes of the profile picture -

```
https://graph.facebook.com/UID/picture?type=large
```

The values that are accepted are -

- small
- normal
- large
- square

Comment: Thank you very much Lix, I will add the line to each score field besides the user info with respective user ID.Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer, I really appreciate it pal!